# Masking NsImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image

How would I be able to mask an nsimageview in objective c?  For example, having an nsimageview with rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. If you want to draw an image in a way that NSImageView doesn't support, you'll need to make your own view to draw it.

The only other way would be to mask the image itself before passing it off to the image view.